# Validar un textBox en C# Visual Studio WindowsForms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un textBox llamado **`txtSSID`** y quiero validar que solamente se ingrese letras(No todas), números y algunos caracteres especiales:

No permitir letras como las que detallo a continuación (Mayúsculas o minúsculas):

> 'é', 'ý', 'ú', 'í', 'ñ', 'ó', 'á', 'ë', 'ÿ', 'ü', 'ï', 'ö','ä','ê','û','î','ô','â'

Tengo este código:

```
char[] NoPermitir = { 'é', 'ý', 'ú', 'í', ' ', 'ñ', 'ó', 'á', 'ë', 'ÿ', 'ü', 'ï', 'ö', 'ä','ê','û','î','ô','â'};
```

Permitir carácter especial como las que detallo a continuación:

> '-', '_'

Tengo este código:

```
char[] Permitir = { '-', '_'};
```

Este es el código completo que me valida todas las letras incluyendo la **ñ, las tildes y otros caracteres del español** cosa que no quiero que sea así, también valida números y admite el `BakcSpace`(La tecla que sirve para borrar) este es el código:

```
private void txtSSID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char[] NoPermitir = { 'é', 'ý', 'ú', 'í', 'ñ', 'ó', 'á', 'ë', 'ÿ', 'ü', 'ï', 'ö', 'ä','ê','û','î','ô','â'};
        char[] Permitir = { '-', '_'};

        if (!(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar)) && (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back) && !(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Solo se permiten letras y números", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSSID.Text))
        {
            label1.Text = "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "Correcto";
        }
    }
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que también me valide el **`Char[] Permitir`** y **`Char[]NoPermitir`** en mi textBox **`txtSSID`.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con la función `Contains` de la siguiente forma:

```
private void txtSSID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char[] NoPermitir = { 'é', 'ý', 'ú', 'í', 'ñ', 'ó', 'á', 'ë', 'ÿ', 'ü', 'ï', 'ö', 'ä','ê','û','î','ô','â'};
    char[] Permitir = { '-', '_'};

    //Validamos si el carácter es un valor permitido, si es falso entramos
    if (!Permitir.Contains(e.KeyChar))
    {
        //Validamos que el valor sea un carácter no permitido
        if (NoPermitir.Contains(e.KeyChar))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Carácter no permitido.", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //Si no es un carácter no permitido validamos que sea letra y numero o la tecla back
            if (!(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar)) && (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back) && !(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Solo se permiten letras y números", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSSID.Text))
    {
        label1.Text = "Error";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "Correcto";
    }
}
```

Comment: Disculpa por responder tarde, pero si me funcionó muchas  gracias @Marc.